# Properly serializing/unserializing primitives with Endian in mind

Tags: c++, serialization

For a project, I'm trying to serialize some primitives and send them over the wire to a locally hosted Java server. The Java part isn't so important right now, but what is important is that Java interprets its data as Big Endian, whereas my C++ program is Little Endian.

For a small example, I have a double:

```
_fields.degLatitude = 50.0;
```

I then want to serialize that data, but also swap the byte order (to conform to Little->Big Endian):

```
char buffer[sizeof(struct Fields)];
char* p = buffer;

writeReversedData<double>(&p, _fields.degLatitude);
```

writeReversedData's implementation is here:

```
template <typename T> void JsbSimWrapper::writeReversedData(char** bb, T& data)
{
    const char* charBuffer = std::to_string(data).c_str();

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++)
    {
        (*bb)[i] = charBuffer[sizeof(T) - i - 1];
    }

    *bb += sizeof(T);
}
```

Then just as a test on my side, I wanted to unserialize that data then swap it back to Little Endian:

```
std::cout << getReversedData<double>(&p) << std::endl;
```

And here's getReversedData's implementation:

```
template <typename T> T JsbSimWrapper::getReversedData(char** p)
{
    union temp 
    {
        char bytes[sizeof(T)];
        T tt;
    };

    temp t;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++)
    {
        t.bytes[i] = (*p)[(sizeof(T) - 1) - i];
    }

    *p += sizeof(T);

    return t.tt;
}
```

Unfortunately, cout just returns huge numbers that aren't even close to 50.0. I also tested the data received on the Java end, and it matches up with the cout in the C++, so it has to be something with my write call.

I know for sure that my getReversedData works, because I tested it with the Java side sending me serialized data, and the C++ side interprets it just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code stores a pointer to a temporary. It will be dangling as soon as the statement completes.

```
const char* charBuffer = std::to_string(data).c_str();
```

Also, in the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++)
{
    (*bb)[i] = charBuffer[sizeof(T) - i - 1];
}
```

there is no rule that the string representation is `sizeof(T)`. For example, a 4 byte int might convert to 10 digits.

It would be much better to store the converted result in a `std::string` and then use the `length()` of that string.